# SharedPreferences in a edittext of a AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I'm using `TextToSpeech` for the first time and i have a problem.. I created a dialog with a editText where i can write something:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  value = input.getText().toString();
  // Do something with value!
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
  }
});

alert.show();
```

I need save in preferences that value.

I created this one:

```
private void prefvalue(String tag) {
  String name = savename.getString(Tag, null);
  SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savename.edit();
  preferencesEditor.putString("tag", tag);
  preferencesEditor.commit();
}
```

well.. now in onCreate what have i to do? Because i tried do something like

```
input.setText(savename.getString("tag", Default Value"));
```

where `input` is the editText inside the AlertDialog. But of course doesn't work because it doesn't find the `input` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save that value on Click of positive button.

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
value = input.getText().toString();

 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreference("MyKey",0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sp.edit();
 preferencesEditor.putString("tag", value);
 preferencesEditor.commit();

}
});
```

Now retrieve anywhere where you want.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreference("MyKey",0);
String data = sp.getString("tag","");
```

Now set this data string to your EditText.

Comment: yeah could be a great idea thanks. I didn't think about this solution :) I'll try thanks

Comment: So if i want display the `value` in the edittext or TextView for example, i need take `data` and put it inside them? is this what you mean with `Now set this data string to your EditText`?

Comment: means if you have textView then set textView.setText(data);

Comment: Exactly perfect! Thanks. Accepted the answere

Comment: @End.Game Wel come.Glad to help you!